# picamera with python with opencv cv2.cvtColor error scn == 3 || scn == 4

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am using `raspberry pi camera` and `python` with `opencv`.is the camera didn't work?
Below is my code snippet:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import picamera 
face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

eye_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, img=cap.read()
    gray= cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces= face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y),(x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 2)
        roi_gray= gray[y:y+h ,x:x+w]
        roi_color= imb[y:y+h ,x:x+w]
        eyes= eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for(ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
            cv2.recangle(roi_color, (ex,ey), (ex+ew,ey+eh), (0,255,0),2)

    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    k=cv2.waitKey(30)  &0xff
    if k==27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/face eye detect.py", line 12, in <module>
gray= cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
error: /build/opencv-U1UwfN/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg1/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3737: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

Comment: what happens if you check if `img` is not empty first ?

Comment: sorry sir but can you tell me how to check it ,i am a beginner
by the way,i follow the video below
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88HdqNDQsEk&t=411s
i think it wont generate any file

Comment: What @GeorgeProfenza meant was within the `while` loop add this line `if img =='None': print('Image not found')`. This will let you know whether image is actually captured or not

Comment: I've posted details bellow, bare in mind you don't want to check against a string(`'None'` is not the same as `None`)

Answer (score 1):

You can check try checking if the frame returned isn't empty first (might take a bit for the camera to open and send full valid frames ?):

```
if img is not None
```

e.g.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import picamera 
face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

eye_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, img=cap.read()
    if img is not None:
        gray= cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces= face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
        for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y),(x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 2)
            roi_gray= gray[y:y+h ,x:x+w]
            roi_color= imb[y:y+h ,x:x+w]
            eyes= eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
            for(ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
                cv2.recangle(roi_color, (ex,ey), (ex+ew,ey+eh), (0,255,0),2)

        cv2.imshow('img',img)
    else:
        print 'empty camera frame, skipping processing'
    k=cv2.waitKey(30)  &0xff
    if k==27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It's worth checking out [Adrian's PiCamera OpenCV tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/).
Bare in mind you can use the [picamera module](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/) to set the camera to retrieve images in [YUV format](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes2.html?highlight=yuv#unencoded-image-capture-yuv-format) instead of RGB. The reason is that you can simply retrieve the Y channel (luminosity) directly, without having to convert from RGB to grayscale (saving processing power for better things).

Additionally, if accuracy isn't crucial, but speed is, you might want to look into [LBP cascades](https://www.superdatascience.com/opencv-face-detection/) instead of HAAR cascades.

These are just some pointers, start off with what's most comfortable for you first then built on top.